# Как изменить радиус градиента

Tags: javascript, градиент

Возник такой вопрос. как изменить радиус градиента через js???

Либо что я делаю не так? Хотелось бы получить ответ на чистом js.

```
https://codepen.io/RedSkyby/pen/wjEWNM
```

```js
var curcle = document.getElementById("curcle");

window.onload = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    curcle.style.background = "radial-gradient([i]em, #667db6 , #0082c8 ,#0082c8 ,#667db6)"; //тут я меняю радиус ,если I подставлять вручную - всё работает
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#curcle {
  background: radial-gradient(18em, #667db6, #0082c8, #0082c8, #667db6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="curcle"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: у тебя небольшая ошибка, нужно написать `curcle.style.background = "radial-gradient(" + i + "em, #667db6...`, но даже если ты напишешь верно то этот код выполнится за столь короткое время, что глаз не заметит изменение градиента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
window.onload = () => {
  var curcle = document.getElementById("curcle");

  // Array(20).fill(0).forEach((x, idx) =>
  //    setTimeout(() => curcle.style.background = `radial-gradient(${idx}em, #667db6, #0082c8, #0082c8, #667db6)`, idx * 100));

  for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    setTimeout(() => curcle.style.background = `radial-gradient(${i}em, #667db6, #0082c8, #0082c8, #667db6)`, i * 100);
  } 
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#curcle {
  background: radial-gradient(18em, #667db6, #0082c8, #0082c8, #667db6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="curcle"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var curcle = document.getElementById("curcle");

window.onload = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  console.log(i);
    curcle.style.background = "radial-gradient("+i+" em, #667db6 , #0082c8 ,#0082c8 ,#667db6)"; //тут я меняю радиус ,если I подставлять вручную - всё работает
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#curcle {
  background: radial-gradient(18em, #667db6, #0082c8, #0082c8, #667db6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="curcle"></div>
</body>
```